# How to get parent Widget width

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a card view Widget and inside that a *Text Widget* but it is showing overflowed by 1.00pixels 

Is there any way to set Text fit to parent width

```
Container(
            child: Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
              child: Column(
                children: getDetailsItems(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Here getDetailsItems return a list of Widget it include *Text Widget*

```
List<Widget> getDetailsItems() {
    List<Widget> l = [];

    if (mItem.mServiceDetail != null) {
      for (int i = 0; i < mItem.mServiceDetail.length; i++) {
        Row r1 = Row(
          children: <Widget>[],
        );
        Align a1 = Align(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Container(
                child: SizedBox(
              width: 24,
              height: 24,
              child: Image.network(mItem.mServiceDetail[i].img),
            )),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        );
        Align a2 = Align(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Container(

                child: Align(
              child:  Text(
                (mItem.mServiceDetail[i].title == null
                    ? ""
                    : mItem.mServiceDetail[i].title),
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16),
              ),
            )),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        );

        r1.children.add((a1));
        r1.children.add((a2));

        l.add(r1);
      }
    }

    return l;
  }
```

[image]

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a direct child of your `Row` you can wrap your `Align` widget with a `Flexible` widget. This will prevent its child from overflowing. Note that this can only be used for direct children of `RenderFlex` widget as `Column` or `Row`. So in your case:

```
Flexible a2 = Flexible(
  child: Align(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Container(
        child: Align(
          child: Text(
            mItem.mServiceDetail[i].title == null
                ? ""
                : mItem.mServiceDetail[i].title,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
  ),
);
```

I have added the `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` property to make it visible.

As a general tip I would recommend you to add children of something like `Row` directly and skip using those local variables as most stuff in `Flutter` is added instantly as part of its declarative form. So your method should look like this:

```
List<Widget> getDetailsItems() {
  List<Widget> l = [];

  if (mItem.mServiceDetail != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < mItem.mServiceDetail.length; i++) {
      l.add(
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Container(
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: 24,
                    height: 24,
                    child: Image.network(mItem.mServiceDetail[i].img),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Align(
                      child: Text(
                        mItem.mServiceDetail[i].title == null
                            ? ""
                            : mItem.mServiceDetail[i].title,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
  }
  return l;
}
```

Seeing you use this function to create those entries in a specific way is also a good indicator that it should be a `Widget` itself so you could even create a new `StatefulWidget` for that.